# If not found in record then get other where case in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to check in `where` case that if not found `where type='P'` then it take record of `type='C'`

here is table

```
paper_id  | product_id  | type
    1          1           P
    2          1           P
    3          1           C
    4          1           C
    5          2           C
    6          2           C
```

There is `product_id` `1` and `2`, need to get those record that have `type='P'` but those product who have not `type='P'` the record get from record `type='C'`

after query need this result

```
paper_id  | product_id  | type
    1          1           P
    2          1           P
    5          2           C
    6          2           C
```

i try

`select * from table where CASE WHEN type !='P' THEN type='C' ELSE type='P'END`

but not working

Comment: For completeness, what if they don't have type c?

Comment: You mean to say, you want only one type per product.

Comment: yes @Rahul, Need At a time onle type, it P is avalable then P else C

Comment: @Strawberry if not c then not give rocord

Answer (score 0):

```
select paper_id, product_id, type from your_tab
where type = 'P'
union all
select t1.paper_id, t1.product_id, t1.type from your_tab t1
where t1.type = 'C'
  and not exists (select 1 from your_tab t2 
                  where t2.product_id = t1.product_id and t2.type = 'P');
```

Comment: thank you for  your way is right but need to use only ` CASE WHEN ` type of query

Comment: @Mark Richards I made a small mistake in the EXISTS subquery. Should be 't2.product_id = t1.product_id'

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

`SELECT DISTINCT T.PRODUCT_ID, T.PAPER_ID, T.TYPE
  FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 WHERE (CASE
         WHEN T.TYPE = 'P' THEN
          'TRUE'
         WHEN T.TYPE != 'P' THEN
          (CASE
            WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM YOUR_TABLE T2
                   WHERE T2.PRODUCT_ID = T.PRODUCT_ID
                     AND T2.TYPE = 'P') = 0 THEN
             'TRUE'
            ELSE
             'FALSE'
          END)
       END) = 'TRUE'`